# `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationExceptionExportRenderer` on ExportRenderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I try to realize custom rendering for `Editor` and follow [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVGRP.png) instructions, just used `Editor` instead `Entry`:

Inside Xamarin project I have defined new class `CustomEditor`:

```
public class CustomEditor : Editor
{

}
```

And inside Xamarin.Android this one:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEditor), typeof(CustomEditorRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.Android
{
    class CustomEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
        public CustomEditorRenderer(Context context) : base(context) {}

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.LightGreen);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The app builds and compiles normally, but I get the error when I try to access CustomEditor:

```
var st = new StackLayout();
st.Children.Add(new CustomEditor()); // <= here
```

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation

After all I have defined what the `CustomEditorRenderer` constructor start initialization and `context` arrives to `base()`:

[image]

but after that on press F10 (F11) for next step occurs the error.

[image]

I cann't understand what I'm doing wrong

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVGRP.png): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry#creating-the-custom-renderer-on-androidUnhandled Exception:

Comment: what is the InnerException?

Comment: @Jason, I can 't understand the details of the error. Only `Unhandled Exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation`

Comment: the Exception object has an InnerException property that will typically show you more useful information about what is actually causing the problem.  You need to use the debugger to look at the InnerException

Comment: @Jason, I don 't know how to get it. I cann't wrap `base(context)` into `try/catch`. I disabled check box on "enabled just my code" and enabled debug inside the .net framework source (I hoped its helps me to enter inside `base(context)` for debugging, but not sucess)

Comment: The exception window that pops up should have some button that says "view detail" or something like that to allow you to examine the exception object.

Comment: Is there any other code in your project? I just use your code and it works on my side. I uploaded a [sample project here](https://github.com/XfHua/editor-renderer) and you can check it.

Comment: After all I was helped by deleting bin and obj folders and rebuilding the projects